# How can I get Visual Studio to fully accept my MySQL Data Source?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, resourceproviderfactory

I am able to successfully get through the "Add New Data Source" steps in my C# project in Visual Studio, and get a connection to my MySQL database. However, when I then try to proceed (Note: AFTER it says my connection was successful, and I am able to select my Database name from the dropdown), I get this:

[image]

Researching this, it seems the usual suggestion is to re-download the ADO.NET Driver for MySQL (Connector/NET), which I did -- I downloaded and installed *mysql-connector-net-8.0.21.msi*. But I still get the same problem/error message.

Is it that I need to add one or more of the References depicted below to my project first?

[image]

If not, what am I missing to configure my project so that I can access the MySql database from my Visual Studio app?

### UPDATE

This doesn't answer my question, so I won't do that, but I was able to solve my real problem, which was getting a connection to the database and inserting records into it.

I still get the same err msg I complain about above, but I guess it doesn't matter because, as I said, I successfully updated the database.

Here's how that happened:

While waiting for an answer to my question, I continued doing what I could. I found some code for inserting records using C# into MySql and added it to my code. Intellisense saw that I needed to install the MySql package:

[image]

...so I had it do just that. It automatically also added the necessary uses clause for me while it was at it.

All's well that ends swell.

Comment: I suppose that you have already checked if your project contains the reference to the MySql connector, right?

Comment: It has no such reference. I added System.Data.Services.Client, but that made no difference, either. Where would the MySQL connector reference be located so that I can add it to my references?

Comment: No you should have a reference to MySql.Data (from NuGet) and then add the proper _using MySql.Data.MySqlClient_

Comment: Steve, thanks, you're right! (You probably knew that). I added those kind of indirectly, though. I will update my question (I was able to update the database table, but I still get the same err msg, but I guess I don't care now).

Comment: If you want to make your second comment an answer, Steve, I'll accept it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with a MySql database you need to have a reference to the appropriate ADO driver. This driver known as MySql/Connector could be downloaded from the MySql site, or you can simply use the NuGet Package Manager right-clicking on your references node and then search for MySql.Data package.

After installing it into your project you should still add a *using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;* in all files when you interact with this library.

Answer (score 1):

I work on Django using VS Code with MySQL database
i had to install mysqlclient to connect with my database
Try installing mysqlclient on terminal with command **pip install mysqlclient** on the directory you are working.